# Select by week only in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, frontend

The user should be able click and drag over the date range they want to choose. The date picker would then select entire weeks based on what weeks were between the mouse down and mouse up/release button. (shown below). It is important that the entire week be selected instead of individual dates since the data marts only contain weekly snapshots. By default, only the current week is
selected.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should let us know what you've researched and tried and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: i have tried this one but it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/9usq3enn/ bootstrap date-picker is working fine but datetimepicker not working. here is my included js files - http://prntscr.com/gxazz8

Comment: I found exact solution as i need . - https://jsfiddle.net/prtk/znbx32j1/1/
Thanks @prateek